# Как сделать чтобы в MiniTest Ruby определял нормально оператор puts

Tags: ruby, тестирование, testng

Написал простую программу решил, проверить MiniTest эту программу.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
class Test1
attr_accessor :x   
def z
 "Hello #{@x}"   
end
end
class Test2<MiniTest::Test
def test_h  
@xx=Test1.new
@xx.x="World"
puts assert_equal "Hello World",@xx.z
end
end
```

Ошибок MiniTest не выдает, но когда я добавил оператор puts вот пример кода, мне он выдает ошибку.

```
 require 'minitest/autorun'
    class Test1
    attr_accessor :x   
    def z
    puts "Hello #{@x}"   
    end
    end
    class Test2<MiniTest::Test
    def test_h  
    @xx=Test1.new
    @xx.x="World"
    puts assert_equal "Hello World",@xx.z
    end
    end
```

Что сделать в коде чтоб MiniTest воспринимал puts нормально?

Comment: `puts` не оператор, а метод. Заведите себе привычку нормально расставлять отступы, чтобы можно было визуально выделить тело класса и отдельных его методов. И что за ошибку выдаёт, если добавить `puts`?

Answer (score 0):

Я не нашел прямого решения и нашел обходной вариант. Я использую встроееный `gem` `logger`

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html

пример использования

`@logger = Logger.new(STDERR)`

и потом

`@logger.info('anything you want')`